# How come we can't conduct t-test and f-test in MLE?

Tags: t-test, maximum-likelihood, f-test

Isn't the equation derived using MLE a regression? Doesn't that allow for t and f test?

Please help, thanks.

Comment: "*Isn't the equation derived using MLE a regression?*" -- no, not generally. In fact  this suggests a profound misunderstanding of MLE in general.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks can you answer the question also?

Comment: Which question? You ask two questions, I have answered the first - "no". Since the second question is predicated on the first being the case (it's not, as I said), the second question cannot make any sense without some new context in which it might apply - but if you must, then I'd have thought that the answer was obvious "no, MLE doesn't in general allow for an f or a t-test because the reasoning on which you based the conclusion was flawed as I said in my first comment". If you edit your question to one that has an answer beyond 'your understanding of MLE is mistaken', I'll do my best.